# How do I make the colours readable in iPython 5?

Tags: ipython

I've just upgraded to iPython 5 and all the colours are hard to read with my dark terminal background. Is there a way to adjust these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a config file for the default profile:

```
❯ ipython profile create default
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: '/Users/alex/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py'
```

And then modify this file to include the following lines:

```
## Set the color scheme (NoColor, Neutral, Linux, or LightBG).
c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'linux'
```

You can read about the available color schemes here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html